# How to get JVM parameter from *.ini file in code?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, jvm, ini

I have next trouble:
There is eclipse.ini file with some default [key = value] pairs. When I run Eclipse (see documentation: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) **All lines after -vmargs are passed as arguments to the JVM, so all arguments and options for eclipse must be specified before -vmargs**
So, how can I get this params in code via Java? When I pass them through VM Options in Eclipse as is and get

```
RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
Map<String, String> listOfArguments = runtimeMxBean.getSystemProperties();
```

I can see all params, but how I can get them in code (default params from eclipse.ini for example)

Comment: Is it the system property `eclipse.commands` what you're looking for? See _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_ tab _Configuration_.

Comment: Eclipse plug-ins can get the arguments in the `IApplicationContext` - are you asking about plugins? Show us an example of what values you are trying to access and from where.

Comment: @howlger For example I want to add some a new property to eclipse.ini and want to get it in java code in another application which have dependency to eclipse plugin. In my opinion when the eclipse is starting all params from eclipse.ini going to JVM and I can to get them.

Comment: @greg-449 I have eclipse plugin app and java app. I want to run plugin (run eclipse) after that all properties from eclipse.ini go to JVM (refer to documentation) and get them in java app in code directly

Comment: A Java app has no access to those parameters. Again tell us exactly what values you are trying to access.

Comment: @greg-449 for example I want to get value (1.5) of param (from eclipse.ini) -> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
I have maven dependencies to eclipse plugin, when I launch eclipse I will not have access to eclipse.ini params in Java app despite maven dependencies?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see where maven enters in to this. [edit] your question and explain in **much** more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: @greg-449 alright, just tell me: I run Eclipse, in root folder I have eclipse.ini file with default values. Can I get some value of property from this file by key in Eclipse by code?

Comment: Things defined after the -vmargs with -Dxxxx are just put in the normal system properties and an Eclipse plug-in can access them through System.getProperty.

Comment: @greg-449 I thought that's true, but i can't get any property by any key :(
for example: -DtestKey=testValue
String value = System.getProperty("testKey");

And I got null...

Comment: This is only in an Eclipse plug-in installed in that Eclipse. If you run a test plug-in using 'Run Eclipse Application' a separate Eclipse is started with different values.

Comment: @greg-449 and if I run just Eclipse without any plugins I have eclipse.ini in root folder. This will be work? Just Eclipse, not plugin.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. What will work? Only the plug-ins in that Eclipse can access these values.

Comment: If you run/debug a Java or Eclipse application, JUnit test or Maven build from within Eclipse, a new JRE instance is started as a separate process and you have to pass the value in the launch configuration via variables to this VM (in the launch configuration in the tab _Arguments_: `-DtestKey=${system_property:testKey}`).